# Unable to delete Custom Field on ORDER Object

Tags: custom-field

Good day,

I have created some custom fields on the **order** object, And now I am trying to delete those custom fields but I can't.some explain to me why it is happening. for reference, an attachment is added.

Thank you in advance...[image]

Comment: I hope the Accountid, Status and ShippingAddress are the standard fields. These you may not be able to delete them.

Comment: Thank you, Praveen. But those are custom fields.

Comment: The highlighted fields are standard fields that you cannot delete.  Are you referring to the Order page layout?  These fields are required on those layouts there and cannot be removed.

Comment: @RamamanojKothapalli, The fields which you highlited are standard fields as per the below  article https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_order.htm

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala, Yes what you told is correct. I have created order as a custom object also so I was confused. once again thank you for replying

Comment: @akarnid Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the Screenshot which is shared is of Standard Object Order where the fields highlighted are standard fields that Salesforce has given us as per the below [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_order.htm).

You cannot delete any standard fields or objects that Salesforce has given.